# Python's webbrowser opens data URI in IE

Tags: python, browser, data-uri

I'm trying to open a data URI in the default browser and it opens it in IE instead. I have this line:

```
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

which correctly opens up an URL like `http://google.com` for example in `Firefox`.

But when I use a data URI like

> data:image/jpeg;base64,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

it opens up in `Internet Explorer`, which is not my default browser, and can't open it correctly too.

*Disclaimer: I'm new to python*

Comment: Please include an example of a data URL you try to open.